# How to use the Media attribute in apex stylesheet

Tags: visualforce, stylesheets

When I used the below code, its work fine.

```
<link href='https://e13.salesforce.com/resource/3243243242342/resorcename/css/treeview.print.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />
```

But above is seems to be the hard-code. So i have used the below code.

```
<apex: stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.resorcename, 'css/treeview.print.css')}"/>
```

It doesnt work. the problem is i have used the " media='print' " in the first code. So how to use this attribute in my apex:stylesheet.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`<apex:stylesheet>`](https://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_compref_stylesheet.htm) supports [HTML pass-through attributes](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/pages_html_features_pass_through_attributes.htm) using the `html-` prefix. This means that you can use the Apex tag like this:

```
<apex:stylesheet
    value="{!URLFOR($Resource.resorcename, 'css/treeview.print.css')}"
    html-media="print"/>
```

which will produce this output:

```
<link
    https://e13.salesforce.com/resource/3243243242342/resorcename/css/treeview.print.css' 
    rel='stylesheet' 
    media='print' />
```